# Redirect based on whether downloadable file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Is it possible to achieve the following via htaccess/mod_rewrite:

If a user attempts to download a file e.g. `http://static.example.com/im a downloadable file.pdf` and the file does not exist, it redirects to the same named file but with the spaces replaced by underscores, e.g. `http://static.example.com/im_a_downloadable_file.pdf`

Thanks for any help you can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting and challenging problem.

Use these 2 rules for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s.*)$" $1_$2 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s(\S*)$" $1_$2 [L]
```

`im a downloadable file.pdf` will be internally forwarded to `im_a_downloadable_file.pdf` only if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'll try it out and let you know the result!

Comment: Apologies, only just got round to trying your fix. I popped the htaccess in the same folder as the downloadable files (domain.com/downloads/subfolder/xxxx) and it doesn't seem to be working. Is it because I didn't mention that the downloads are a few folders deep?

Comment: Yes that will definitely change the code in my answer. Before that I need to know what are some examples of your download file links?